# Watch directive scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Context**

My controller stores an array. When pressing a specific shortcut on the keyboard I add a new object to this array.

The array is used inside a directive to display a chart.

So, on shortcut pressed the chart should be updated with the new value.

**Controller**

```
vm.observation = [{
    "sale": "202",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "sale": "215",
    "year": "2011"
}, {
    "sale": "179",
    "year": "2012"
}, {
    "sale": "199",
    "year": "2013"
}, {
    "sale": "134",
    "year": "2014"
}, {
    "sale": "176",
    "year": "2015"
}];
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('spwApp.directives')
    .directive('linechart', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                id: "@",
                observation: "="
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch("observation", function(newVal, oldVal){
                    console.log("OBS : " + newVal);
                }, true);
            }
        }
    }])
```

**HTML**

```
<linechart id="linechart3" observation="vm.observation"></linechart>
```

When the page load the chart correctly display the data and the console correctly log inside `$watch` is correctly executed.

Anyway after pressing the shortcut the `$watch` is not triggered whereas the array is updated

I can't find the error in my code

Comment: Try using $watchCollection instead of $watch

Comment: @Sajeetharan It now goes inside `$watch()` but generates this error `$apply already in progress`

Comment: @GeorgeLee It seems to work. Could you please post and answer with the explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add something to the array, but the array itself stays the same. A regular watcher only reacts to a value that changes. That's why Angular also provides `$watchCollection`:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("observation",
```

`$watchCollection` also monitors the content of the array, i.e. it checks if something was removed or added.

Comment: Pretty much this, using $watch it's going Array is still equal to an Array so no change, you can also do `$scope.$watch('observation',function(),true)` the true will do a "deep" comparison but this comes with a performance hit

Comment: @GeorgeLee You are right about using deep comparison, but `$watchCollection` is more efficient / performant.